# Mapping Nested JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I try to mapping nested JSON in React JS.

My JSON data like this,

```
"beautifuldata": [
{ "id":"1", "name":"a"},
{ "id":"2", "name":"b"},
{ "id":"3", "name":"c"},
{ "id":"4", "name":"d"},
{ "id":"5", "name":"e"},
{ "id":"6", "name":"f"},
{ "id":"7", "name":"g"}]
```

this data came from an API. And I can write my data to the console. But everything went wrong when I try to access the inner side. For example, I want to get id from my JSON data,

I try this

```
[beautifuldata].map(x => console.log(x));
```

this code line gave all data,

```
[beautifuldata].map(x => console.log(x.id));
```

this code line gave me undefined. I want to access all data inside my JSON. What am I missing?

Comment: `[beautifuldata].map(x => x.id);`

Comment: `[beautifuldata].map(x => console.log(x));` "this code line gave all data" - I seriously doubt that. `console.log()` returns undefined, so regardless of whether you pass it `x` or `x.id`, it won't matter - you'll still get an array of undefined's. Perhaps you did `map(x => x)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are returning the whatever `console.log(x.id)` returns which is `undefined`;

You need to return the `x.id`

```js
let obj = {
  beautifuldata: [
    { id: "1", name: "a" },
    { id: "2", name: "b" },
    { id: "3", name: "c" },
    { id: "4", name: "d" },
    { id: "5", name: "e" },
    { id: "6", name: "f" },
    { id: "7", name: "g" },
  ],
};

const result = obj.beautifuldata.map((x) => x.id);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

remove [ ] from this line

```
[beautifuldata].map(x => console.log(x.id));
```

To read

```
beautifuldata.map(x => console.log(x.id));
```

EDIT

If you want to access data outside the map function,

```js
    beautifuldata.map(x => {
        /* Work with x properties here*/ 
        console.log(x.id)
        return x
    }
    // thanks to @mhodges
```

Comment: `console.log()` returns undefined.. you are implicitly returning the return value of console.log to your map function, which would result in an array of undefined's

Comment: Yeah, that's very true, but it's what @nebula wanted, to access data inside the map function, if I got it right. But I got the point, it's worth a take. thanks for the remainder

Comment: I'll remove my downvote because I think it's pretty unclear what the OP is looking for. They are probably confused about the difference between the return value of `.map()` and what they are seeing in the console print from `console.log()`. It's likely that the solution requires both changes, as @decpk did above

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a solution like below might be an appropriate approach.

```
var rst = {
"beautifuldata": [
{ "id":"1", "name":"a"},
{ "id":"2", "name":"b"},
{ "id":"3", "name":"c"},
{ "id":"4", "name":"d"},
{ "id":"5", "name":"e"},
{ "id":"6", "name":"f"},
{ "id":"7", "name":"g"}]
}

rst.beautifuldata.map(i => console.log(i.id));
/* -- or --- */
rst.beautifuldata.forEach(i => console.log(i.id));
```

Hope that helps or gives you a hint.